# I can't find my Images folder using the command line

Tags: command-line, user-folders

I'm trying to run exiftool to remove GPS data in some of my files, but I can't find my Images Folder, on Windows 10.

If I do a DIR command in my User folder, the following shows up

```
21/01/2021  15:43    <DIR>          .
21/01/2021  15:43    <DIR>          ..
03/11/2020  06:05    <DIR>          .dbus-keyrings
01/01/2020  17:24    <DIR>          .idlerc
02/05/2019  15:14    <DIR>          .Origin
04/01/2020  15:47    <DIR>          .PyCharmCE2019.3
16/01/2021  23:00    <DIR>          .pylint.d
02/05/2019  15:14    <DIR>          .QtWebEngineProcess
16/01/2021  21:55    <DIR>          .vscode
31/07/2019  17:22    <DIR>          .vscode-glitch
14/01/2021  05:30    <DIR>          3D Objects
03/12/2020  15:00    <DIR>          Biblioteca do calibre
14/01/2021  05:30    <DIR>          Contacts
16/01/2021  21:55    <DIR>          Desktop
31/01/2021  14:48    <DIR>          Documents
31/01/2021  14:33    <DIR>          Downloads
14/01/2021  05:30    <DIR>          Favorites
14/01/2021  05:30    <DIR>          Links
14/01/2021  05:30    <DIR>          Music
17/01/2021  09:56    <DIR>          OneDrive
05/01/2020  12:46    <DIR>          PycharmProjects
14/01/2021  05:30    <DIR>          Saved Games
14/01/2021  05:30    <DIR>          Searches
14/01/2021  05:30    <DIR>          Videos
23/01/2021  23:40    <DIR>          Zotero
```

There's even 3d Objects, **but not the Images folder**. Is there some reason why? I tried looking up the "Public" folder, and there is a Pictures folder there, but it's empty.

Comment: nevermind, I found the problem. See, I sync the Images folder with OneDrive, so Windows change the path to C:\Users\Tet\OneDrive. Simple mistake of my own.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because OP found the error.